# When using flask_login, how to pass an argument to login_manager.login_view?

Tags: flask, flask-login

I have a login route like this

```
@app.route('/login/<int:user_id>)
def login(user_id):
    if some_condition:
        return redirect(url_for('dashboard', user_id=user_id)
    return render_template('login.html')
```

The route for the dashboard goes like this

```
@app.route('/dashboard/<int:user_id>)
@login_required
def dashboard(user_id):
    # some code...
    return render_template('dashboard.html')
```

Ideally, you shouldn't be able to access the `dashboard` without logging in. Hence, the use of `@login_required` decorator. When a user manually types in the address bar `/dashboard/2` where `2` represents the `user_id`. If the user is not logged in, `dashboard` redirects to `login`. The following line causes that behaviour.

`login_manager.login_view = 'login'`

`login` refers to the name of the login route function. How do i pass the user_id, in this case `2` to  `login_manager.login_view = 'login'`

Comment: I don't know who flagged it, but I guess these are not the answers you want.

Comment: @fatih No, they aren't. can i unflag a question?

Comment: Let me answer you as a comment on your question. Please do not send your `id` as request parameter. It will help you if you examine the `current_user` function of `Flask`.